# 2D Grid of text fields using unity5

Tags: gridview, text, unity-game-engine

I want to create a grid of text like,

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

where all the letters are different text views and clickable, drag-able. i have created a similar looking board with GUI textfields, but the letters aren't accessible through positions. I want a 2D array of texts acting like grid (grid[0,0] will detect A, for e.g.). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

probably I misunderstood but what's wrong with:

```
GUIText[][] grid = new GUIText[3][3];
```

??

Comment: I need all the letters clickable. If I useGUIText, will I be able attach a collider2D to it?

Comment: you can use

  grid[3][3].HitTest (Input.mousePosition);